# Julian Day to ISO 8601 string in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, iso8601, julian-date

I have a table that stores date/time values as julian days in SQLite (using the julianday() function). I can't seem to figure out how to convert them back to ISO 8601 style strings (YYYY-mm-ddThh:m:ss.sss) when I read them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just feed the Julian day number to the [`datetime` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

> A time string can be in any of the following formats:
>   [...]
>   12. DDDDDDDDDD
>   [...]
>   Format 12 is the Julian day number expressed as a floating point value.

So `datetime(julianday_output)` goes in the opposite direction as the `julianday` function:

```
sqlite> select datetime(julianday(current_timestamp)) as dt_from_jd, current_timestamp as dt;
dt_from_jd          | dt
2011-09-30 14:46:52 | 2011-09-30 14:46:52
```

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: This isn't technically 8601 though, as 8601 requires a `T` where sqlite prints a space.

Comment: @rcorre True, not sure how I missed that. If you need strict ISO8601 then `strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', julianday())`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `strftime`? http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: I did see that but it wasn't immediately obvious to me how to make the opposite conversion. I thought %J operates on a string and returns a julian day number (as in SELECT strftime('%J', 'ISO_8601')